# Java BufferdReader returning old value

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-studio, sockets

I have an Android client, written in Java, that contains a login form and a button.

When the button is clicked, an `AuthenticationThread` object instance is created, and the username and password values from the form and the activity context are passed to the `AuthenticationThread` constructor, and the thread starts.

In the thread `run()` method, a socket to the server is created, and the username and password values are sent to the server through a `PrintWriter`. The server checks the database and sends back the string `"succes"` if the user exists in the database, and `"wrong"` otherwise.

Inside the `run()` method, I have created a `BufferedReader` out of the socket. From the `BufferedReader`, the answer is saved in a `final` variable that is sent as an argument to a method of the activity called `changeUi(String ans)` by the method `activity.runOnUiThread()`.

In the `changeUi()` method, if the string argument is equal to `"succes"`, a toast is shown and an `Intent` to another activity is created and activate by `startActivity()`, otherwise a toast is shown saying something isn't right with the details.

The first time the button is clicked, nothing appears to happen on the client side (I checked the server side, and it got a message and sent a response). The second time the button is clicked, the answer that it passed to the `changeUi()` method is the response from the previous username and password.

Here is my code:

LoginActivity:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    TextView tv1,tv2,tv3;
    EditText etn,etp;
    Button btn;
    CheckBox rememberMe;
    Intent i;
    AuthenticationThread thread;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        rememberMe = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1_1);
        tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1_2);
        tv3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1_3);
        etn = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextUN);
        etp = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPassword);
        btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn100);
        tv1.setText("Login");
        tv2.setText("please enter username:");
        tv3.setText("please enter password:");
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view == findViewById(R.id.btn100)){
            thread = new AuthenticationThread(etn.getText().toString(), etp.getText().toString(),this);
            thread.start();
        }
    }

    public void changeUi(String msg){
        if (msg.equals("succes")) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Loged in successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SearchActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "username or password are incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

AuthenticationThread:

```
public class AuthenticationThread extends Thread{
    String name;
    String password;
    LoginActivity loginActivity;

    public AuthenticationThread(String n, String p,LoginActivity l){
        this.name = n;
        this.password = p;
        this.loginActivity = l;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();
        try {
            Socket s = new Socket("192.168.1.33",8888);
            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));
            String msg = "auth;" + name + ";" + password + ";null" ;
            output.print(msg);
            output.flush();
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
            final String response = input.readLine();

            loginActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    loginActivity.changeUi(response);
                }
            });
            s.close();
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

the server side (written in python):

```py
def authenticate(name, pas, client_socket):
    conn.execute("SELECT * FROM tbluser WHERE username="+"'"+name+"'")
    try:
        res = conn.fetchone()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e.args)
        print("data base problem...")

    if(res != None):
        if(res[2] == pas):
                client_socket.send("succes".encode())
                print(str(res[0]) + " has logined now")

        else:
            msg = "wrong".encode()
            client_socket.send(msg)
    else:
            msg = "wrong".encode()
            client_socket.send(msg)
    dataBase.commit()

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print("socket created")
try:
    s.bind((IP,PORT))
    print("socket bind succesfully")
except socket.error as err:
    print("couldnt bind socket " + str(err[0]) + " " + err[1])   
    sys.exit()
    
#waiting for requests and request routing
s.listen(10)
print("listening")
while True:
    client_socket , addr = s.accept()
    msg = str(client_socket.recv(64))
    print('recived from '+ addr[0])
    msg = msg[2:len(msg) - 1].split(";")
    
    if( msg[0] == "auth" and msg[1] != "null" and msg[2] != "null"):
        authenticate(msg[1], msg[2], client_socket)
```

**Answer**: I didnt put EOL character in the response from the server so readLine blocked untill EOL character would automaticlly send in the next message.
the correct server side code is:

```py
def authenticate(name, pas, client_socket):
    conn.execute("SELECT * FROM tbluser WHERE username="+"'"+name+"'")
    try:
        res = conn.fetchone()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e.args)
        print("data base problem...")

    if(res != None):
        if(res[2] == pas):
                client_socket.send("succes\r\n".encode())
                print(str(res[0]) + " has logined now")

        else:
            msg = "wrong\r\n".encode()
            client_socket.send(msg)
    else:
            msg = "wrong\r\n".encode()
            client_socket.send(msg)
    dataBase.commit()

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print("socket created")
try:
    s.bind((IP,PORT))
    print("socket bind succesfully")
except socket.error as err:
    print("couldnt bind socket " + str(err[0]) + " " + err[1])   
    sys.exit()
    
#waiting for requests and request routing
s.listen(10)
print("listening")
while True:
    client_socket , addr = s.accept()
    msg = str(client_socket.recv(64))
    print('recived from '+ addr[0])
    msg = msg[2:len(msg) - 1].split(";")
    
    if( msg[0] == "auth" and msg[1] != "null" and msg[2] != "null"):
        authenticate(msg[1], msg[2], client_socket)
```

Comment: Without seeing the server code, or at least the raw data being transmitted, it is difficult to diagnose your issue. All of your thread variables are local to the thread, they are not being shared by multiple threads. So each thread is guaranteed to be a unique TCP connection. So the logical conclusion is that either 1) the server is not actually sending a response the 1st time, and is sending the wrong response the 2nd time; or 2) the 1st `runOnUiThread()` call is being delayed until after the 2nd button click. I suggest you add some logging to your thread code to see what it is actually doing

Comment: I have checked the traffic between the server and client with wireshark and in the first click the response sent to the client but I will add the relvant code of the server side, thank you.

Comment: `readLine()` will block until an EOL character is found. Verify your server is sending one on the first message. It may add one prior to the next message which is why you get the first one after the second click.

Comment: @DanHarms I agree on making sure EOL is being sent. But the rest of what you said makes no sense when separate TCP connections are being used for each message.

Comment: Yes it was the EOL character, thank you!

Comment: @matanya neither your client or server are sending any kind of terminator at the end of the request/response, such as EOL. You should add that, and then have the receiver read until that terminator is actually received. Also, on the server side, if the client doesn't send a valid request, you are not sending back any response at all. And, the database query is subject to SQL Injection attacks, FYI.